# Kill a port that is listening with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to a kill a listening port in python.

```
os.system("sudo netstat -ap | grep 13000 > net.txt")
f = open("net.txt","r")
fr = f.read()
```

The output of the above command is:

```
udp        0        0*:13000               *:*                  5071/python
```

So far I have:

```
regex = re.compile(\d*.(python))
fl = regex.findall(fr)
```

The above regex just prints python.

So the question is, how do I create a regex to take just the PID value `5071` (this could be any other number)

**EDIT:**
There could be more than one value, as there could be more than one process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive look-ahead :

```
>>> s="udp        0        0*:13000               *:*                  5071/python"
>>> re.search(r'\d+(?=/python)',s).group(0)
'5071'
```

Or even just a normal regex and a group :

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)/python', s).group(1)
'5071'
```

if you have multiple string put the above command in a loop :

```
for s in string_list:
    print re.search(r'(\d+)/python', s).group(1)
```

Comment: I should have added, what if there were multiple strings? Thanks @Kasra

Comment: @JonathanDavies you're welcome so you can put it in a loop ! see the edit !

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a single string, you can skip using `findall` and use `re.search()` instead. You also have no quotes around the pattern that you are trying to compile it seems.

You could use a capturing group and reference that group # to grab your match result.

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)/python', s).group(1)
'5071'
```

If you have multiple strings, you can use the findall method to store the matches in a list.

```
>>> s = '''
udp        0        0*:13000               *:*                  5071/python
udp        0        0*:13000               *:*                  8000/python
'''
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)/python', s)
['5071', '8000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without needing a regex at all:

```
s = "udp        0        0*:13000               *:*                  5071/python"
print(s.rsplit(" ",1)[-1].split("/python")[0])
5071
```

I would also use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) instead of os.system

```
from subprocess  import PIPE,Popen
p1 = Popen(["sudo","netstat", "-ap"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep","13000" ], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=open("net.txt","w"))
p1.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex based on positive lookbehind.

```
(\d+)(?=/python)
```

Output

```
>>> re.search('(\d+)(?=/python)', s).group()
'5071'
```